# SSL Certificate Invalid on back end Node App (Nginx Reverse Proxy)

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I'm having some issues with SSL certificates.

I have a react app running on port 80.
and a node backend running on port 443.

I have a domain pointing to the IP (xx.xx.xxx.xx) which directs to the react app. I'm using nginx to proxy the requests from frontend to backend as I have both on the same server.

Here is the nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80 ssl;
  server_name xx.xx.xxx.xx;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
  root /home/ubuntu/build;
  index index.html;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/build.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/build.error.log;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}

upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:443;
  server 127.0.0.1:443 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s backup;
  keepalive 64;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name xx.xx.xxx.xx;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error when a request is made to the backend:

> net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

this is because the certificate is valid for 'domain.com' and not the IP that the backend is operating on (I know you must use a fully qualified domain for the cert).

My question is what can I do differently (with nginx) that will allow my requests to be made over https on a reverse proxy?

Comment: try `proxy_pass httpS://backend;`?

Comment: already tried it @ThanhNguyenVan but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the standard ports 80 and 443 differently. These ports are the entry points to your server and are not advised to be used as ports running inside reverse proxies.

When using reverse proxies, we map other ports to either port 80 or port 443 so the can be publicly accessible via HTTP or HTTPS respectively.

If we want to access everything by HTTPS, we will need to map both react and node apps to 443 via reverse proxy, and redirect all HTTP access going to HTTPS.

So as suggested steps to fix:

1) Use different ports, say 3000 for react and 3001 for node.

2) Configure your server block listening to port 80 to redirect to https like `return 301 https://<yourdomainhere.com>`

3) Remove `ssl` lines in your port 80 server block. Only use them inside server blocks listening to port 443

4) Modify your `upstream {}` block to use port 3001 for node app. Retain the use of `proxy_pass http://backend;`, it's fine as it is.

5) Add a new location block with `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` inside the server block that listens to port 443.  You will now have two location blocks, one for react and one for node.

6) Define your `server_name` per block with `yourdomainhere.com` since IP addresses are generally not allowed to be issued with SSL certificates. I suggest using a different server block to redirect the IP address to your domain with HTTPS prefix

7) check for errors, then restart nginx.